# OTRS: New module creation for Customer part

Tags: perl, otrs

I have been trying to add a Menu Option in `OTRS` I Followed the [documents](http://doc.otrs.org/developer/3.1/en/html/how-to-extend-otrs.html#writing-new-otrs-frontend-module) provided by `OTRS` for Developers and managed to create a new Hello World Menu (Module) for Agent. I want to do similar thing for Customer Part also. I tried to myself but didn't succeed I would appreciate if anyone could guide me how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: `build the directory /Hello World for the module in the developer directory`. Where is the developer directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register Customer module  just register it via XML file in .../Kernel/Config/Files/yourConfigName.xml like this:

```
<ConfigItem Name="CustomerFrontend::Module###MyCustomModule" Required="0" Valid="1">
        <Description Translatable="1">Frontend module registration for the customer interface.</Description>
        <Group>Ticket</Group>
        <SubGroup>Frontend::Customer::ModuleRegistration</SubGroup>
        <Setting>
            <FrontendModuleReg>
                <Description>My Module Desc</Description>
                <NavBarName>Ticket</NavBarName>
                <Title>My Module</Title>
                <NavBar>
                    <Description Translatable="1">My Module desc</Description>
                    <Name Translatable="1">My Module</Name>
                    <Block></Block>
                    <Type>Submenu</Type>
                    <NavBar>Ticket</NavBar>
                    <Link>Action=MyCustomModule</Link>
                    <LinkOption></LinkOption>
                    <Prio>600</Prio>
                </NavBar>
            </FrontendModuleReg>
        </Setting>
    </ConfigItem>
```

Don't forget to name the module accordingly "MyCustomModule.pm" and in the module itself change the name of autoloaded module